# How to pass file path in a REST API ala Dropbox using Flask-RESTful?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Dropbox has a REST API that allows file upload using the following URL. ([Reference](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put))

`https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/<root>/<path>?param=val`

I want to replicate this API structure using Flask-RESTful. I have the following class.

```
class File(restful.Resource):

    def put(self, fname):
        // do stuff here
```

The class is then automatically mapped with the following code.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)

api.add_resource(File, '/<string:fname>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Uploading a file with the following `curl` command works just fine.

`curl 127.0.0.1:5000/foo.txt -X PUT --data-urlencode file@foo.txt`

However, the following command fails.

`curl 127.0.0.1:5000/foo/bar.txt -X PUT --data-urlencode file@bar.txt`

This is because `127.0.0.1:5000/foo` is treated as another REST resource which isn't mapped in my code.

Is there a method of accomplishing what I want using the Flask-RESTful library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`path`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/routing/#werkzeug.routing.PathConverter) placeholder instead of `string`:

```
api.add_resource(File, '/<path:fname>')
```

Comment: Huh, can't believe I missed that!

Comment: It is easy to miss. I may be wrong but I think there isn't even one example of using `path` in Flask documentation.